# Recover password from SpeedPort DSL router

Tags: router, password-recovery

I'd like to recover the configuration (web interface) admin password of a SpeedPort W 700V router. I've got both wired and wireless access to the router but in both cases the web interface requires the password. I've already found a [way to brute force](http://secunia.com/advisories/product/14218/) the entrance but that's still a lot of work which I'd like to avoid. I also want to avoid a firmware reset since that would erase the whole setup.

Comment: And just in case someone was wondering: a friend owns the router and has forgotten the password …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unlikely to find another method other than brute force or factory reset.  Router manufacturers simply don't provide other mechanisms for recovering lost passwords.  Reset, reconfigure, and move on.  Your time spent messing around with trying to recover the password would be better spent just reconfiguring the router.

Comment: I was suspecting that … question was only on the off chance that somebody knew a clever exploit. +1 anyway.

Comment: There are (I won't name the brand) DSL routers where you just set the new admin username and password in a HTTP GET request. You are not required to be logged on of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin, reset, reconfig, and keep keeping on. There seriously cannot be enough special configuration in a device like this to warrant brute forcing the password.

That said...if you really have to...well...you could do it.

**The following should only be used on networks and devices you own, cracking is lame m'kay?**

You could use [THC Hydra](http://freeworld.thc.org/thc-hydra/) to submit the username and passwords directly to the CGI script on the router.